# Storing static files to be shared among Azure roles

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, azure

I'm trying to host some static files for access by an ASP.Net web role and a separate data worker role that are both running on the same deployment (they use a global static interface).

However, I'm unsure how exactly to 'host' them, I've tried using virtual folders via `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath`, but it only *occasionally* works in debug mode. The files also don't seem to get packaged into the deployment packages made by VS vis CSPack (though this might be a separate issue, is it possible to fix this too?)

The static files in question are actually WordNet, which I'm using through WordNet.Net, If that makes any difference. I also need the solution to work in both the cloud deployment and the emulator (if possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the files are simply read-only, you can place them in an Azure Drive, which is essentially an NTFS-formatted vhd stored in a Page Blob (see [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-create-storage-account/) for more info). Each of your role instances may mount a read-only snapshot of this drive (and one instance may gain write-access at a time).

Storing files on a local disk won't work, because those files aren't replicated across instances; each instance has its own attached storage.

A common pattern is to store content in blobs, possibly in a ZIP file, and then copying those files from Blob Storage to local disk upon instance startup. As an example, you can grab Nate Totten's [Azure Accelerator for Web Roles](http://ntotten.com/2011/08/windows-azure-accelerator-for-web-roles-version-1-1/). You'll see the ZIP file copy technique in action, as it extracts entire websites and unzips them into virtual directories.

Comment: after some fiddling I got the working pretty well, which is why the accept was so late :)

Answer (score 0):

The files may not be being packaged if you haven't set the 'Copy to output directory' property to 'Copy if newer' / 'Copy always'.